# How can I make my columns wrap to better fit long words?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have tried grid classes but none is working. The content is responsive whereas the h2 elements overlap one another. I want them to be stacked when viewing from small devices.

[image: fullscreen layout]

[image: h2 overlay]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <p> Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor </p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">View Details »</button>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p> Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor </p>
      </h2>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p> Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have an extra closing heading tag in your markup. Use a good editor so you spot those things easier. I'm not sure that's a problem, but you should revise the demo above to fix it. Also, please take the [tour] so you know how this site works.

Comment: FYI, this has nothing to do with heading elements. It's simply a matter of word length and space. Your layout needs adjustment to accommodate.

Comment: @DenilShaji, that's not the issue, and answers go down there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the problematic columns full width (12 units) at small screen sizes. You can then bring them down to half width (6 units) at medium and larger screen sizes.

Review the [grid docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#stacked-to-horizontal) for more information.

See the full page demo as well as the compact demo to see the new behavior.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <p> Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor </p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">View Details »</button>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p> Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor </p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p> Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```